# Confused about querying and backtracking

Tags: prolog

I am a little confused about what happens during a query with some rules.
Here is a sample code from my notes.

```
link(fortran, algol60).
link(algol60,cpl).
link(cpl, bcpl).
link(bcpl, c).
link(c, cplusplus).
link(algol60, simula67).
link(simula67, cplusplus).
link(simula67, smalltalk80).

path(L,M) :-   %first path
    link(L,M). %first link

path(L,M) :-   %second path
    link(L,X), %second link
    path(X,M). %third path



 | ?- path(X,bcpl).
```

When we query this, we will call the first path and X will be initiated to cpl since link(cpl,bcpl) is the first thing that matches in our database. So now L = cpl and M = bcpl.
X = cpl? ;
Then we continue by pressing ;

What happens next? Do we call the first path or the second? What happens if we fail a rule, do we start back at the first path?

Comment: You can actually use the tracer to answer your question yourself. Try typing: `?- trace.` at the prompt before trying the same goal and you will see all calls, fails, and redo-s.

Comment: I have tried to follow this but I got lost because I wasn't sure if the third path called the first path or the second path.

Comment: In case you are using SWI-Prolog, the number at the beginning of the line will tell you whether you are going into a new "frame", that is, a new call of the predicate. Anyway, what you are calling "the third path" is a new call of the predicate `path` which has two clauses. Your "first" and "second path" are predicate definitions, while the third "path" is actually a sub-goal. This is a fundamental difference and it is shared by all programming languages I can think of right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pressing `;` you require the next solution. Alternatives in Prolog are expressed with multiple clauses, as you already know.

To be true, an *abstract* interpretation, top down, left to right,  will not try neither the first or the second path/2, but will try first to see if there is another `link(X,bcpl)`.

Because of indexing, SWI-Prolog will not try to call any of these (it knows there is no another link/2 appropriate), and instead will backtrack and will try the next path/2 (the second rule).

Here a (partial) trace: when you see `Redo`, it means that it's selecting the next *alternative* available. The number between parenthesis is the *call level*, but you can see that, for some implementation detail, the proof doesn't start at 1.

```
?- leash(-all), trace, path(X,bcpl).
   Call: (7) path(_G2093, bcpl)
   Call: (8) link(_G2093, bcpl)
   Exit: (8) link(cpl, bcpl)
   Exit: (7) path(cpl, bcpl)
X = cpl ;
   Redo: (7) path(_G2093, bcpl)
   Call: (8) link(_G2093, _G2262)
   Exit: (8) link(fortran, algol60)
   Call: (8) path(algol60, bcpl)
   Call: (9) link(algol60, bcpl)
   Fail: (9) link(algol60, bcpl)
   Redo: (8) path(algol60, bcpl)
   Call: (9) link(algol60, _G2262)
   Exit: (9) link(algol60, cpl)
   Call: (9) path(cpl, bcpl)
   Call: (10) link(cpl, bcpl)
   Exit: (10) link(cpl, bcpl)
   Exit: (9) path(cpl, bcpl)
   Exit: (8) path(algol60, bcpl)
   Exit: (7) path(fortran, bcpl)
X = fortran ;
   Redo: (9) path(cpl, bcpl)
...
   Fail: (8) path(cplusplus, bcpl)
   Redo: (8) link(_G2093, _G2262)
   Exit: (8) link(simula67, smalltalk80)
   Call: (8) path(smalltalk80, bcpl)
   Call: (9) link(smalltalk80, bcpl)
   Fail: (9) link(smalltalk80, bcpl)
   Redo: (8) path(smalltalk80, bcpl)
   Call: (9) link(smalltalk80, _G2262)
   Fail: (9) link(smalltalk80, _G2262)
   Fail: (8) path(smalltalk80, bcpl)
   Fail: (7) path(_G2093, bcpl)
false.
```

Comment: So from what you are saying, after the initial match of link(cpl,bcpl) prolog will try to look for other link(X, bcpl). But since there is none, it will fail and move on to the second path, 
Redo: (7) path(_G2093, bcpl)
is this correct?

Comment: yes, I think so. Try path(X,Y) to see alternative link/2 scanning.